# Is it possible to set a maximum time allowed for android recording using intent?

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I am using the `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`. I was wondering if there is a way to change the maximum time allowed per recording. I TRIED ADDING 
`Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,60000);//max of 60 seconds` 
but it continues recording pass that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please not that MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT is given in seconds, not milliseconds. It only works for post-2.0 devices however.

Answer (score 34):

Actually, `MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT` provide time in **seconds**, NOT in miliseconds!
So you just need to change your value from 60000 to 60 ;)
[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT)

Answer (score 18):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 30000);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY", 0);
startActivityForResult(intent, ActivityRequests.REQUEST_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

This code works well on API 2.2, but the duration limit does not work on API 2.1

`android.intent.extra.durationLimit` was introduced in `API Level 8,` so it's not available in Eclair and earlier, unfortunately. Some device manufacturers may have a proprietary way to set the maximum duration on older devices, which explain why you have seen this working on some pre-Froyo applications.

Comment: you can see the API level at which each variable is introduced by looking to the right side of the gray bar on the Android resources site. For example, see this variable (and it's API level) here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT

Comment: Check this link also: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/donut/packages/apps/Camera/src/com/android/camera/VideoCamera.java .. It will be useful for you

Comment: 3000 here means 50 Minutes, since durationLimit is in seconds not milliseconds

Comment: It's probably better to use the constant MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT defined for "android.intent.extra.durationLimit".

Answer (score 18):

For 30 seconds time, try this code.

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this,here 60 is second
Code:

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Kotlin update to launch `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` Intent with `EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT` set to 60 seconds. As for `putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60)` is taking in seconds as the value for the duration limit.

```
val recordVideoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)

recordVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60)
startActivityForResult(recordVideoIntent, INTENT_VIDEO_RECORD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MediaRecorder`

```
 /**
     * Starts a new recording.
     */
    public void start() throws IOException {

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state
            + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    System.out.println("start() directory >  " + directory);
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
        throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }



    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); // Sets the
    // audio source
    // to be used
    // for recording



    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); // Sets
    // the
    // format
    // of
    // the
    // output
    // file
    // produced
    // during
    // recording.
    // 5 Minutes = 300000 Milliseconds

    recorder.setMaxDuration(300000); // Sets the maximum duration (in ms) of
    // the recording session



    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); // Sets the
    // audio
    // encoder
    // to be
    // used for
    // recording.

    recorder.setOutputFile(path); // Sets the path of the output file to be
    // produced.
    recorder.prepare(); // Prepares the recorder to begin capturing and
    // encoding data.
    recorder.start(); // Recording is now started
```

}

Comment: Thank you Jennifer, I have tried using media recorder to record videos but Its unstable on some platforms such as samsung galaxy. I was hoping that there was a way to just add a maximum time because I need everything that the action_capture intent uses. Any ideas?

Comment: u tried : android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT  right??

Comment: Yeah, i tried that and this intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 60000);. Still nothing.

Comment: try intent.putExtra("android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT", 60000);.